# Barcode Scanner ITF type didn't read correctly [google-mlkit]

Tags: ios, swift, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

[image]I'm trying to read a barcode ITF type on attached image. The correct number should be **858900000000712903282214190708221191640012629178**, but the read number is **85890000000712903282211907082211964001262917**. The qrcode is read correctly.

I'm using MLKitBarcodeScanning 2.0.0 iOS

Thanks

Comment: please attach image..

Comment: Since ITF is a barcode that is prone to misreading, it is better to take measures such as making the resolution of the printer and camera finer, increasing the contrast of the image, or adding a check digit. If it is possible to change to Code128 etc., that may be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to attach the image.

Comment: ITF is known to be flaky due to absence of checksum: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning